# TryParse create inline parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, clr, tryparse

Is there any way in C# to create a variable inline? 
Something like this:

```
int x = int.TryParse("5", out new int intOutParameter) ? intOutParameter : 0;
```

Don´t you think that this is more useful than creating a variable outside and then never use it again?

Comment: Can wrap it in a private method call?

Answer (score 30):

That syntax – called *declaration expressions* – was on the proposed feature list for the next version of C# (version 6).

You're not the only one to think it is useful. For instance making a complete `TryParse` call an expression (no need for a statement to declare the variable).

However it [has been dropped](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820) from the ongoing work to C#6.

<s>I'm sure I'm not the only one hoping it will make a return in a future version.</s>It is included in C#7 as a declaration (no need for `new`):

```
int x = int.TryParse("5", out int intOutParameter) ? intOutParameter : 0;
```

Comment: I can see why they dropped it for now though - too many special cases or handwavey parsing needed to support it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson More a case of seeing F#'s pattern matching and wanting to do something closer to that, solving this will (I hope) thus become part of C# 7.

Answer (score 11):

*Inline declarations for `out` params* is a new suggested feature in C# that might be standard one day, see e.g. [Probable C# 6.0 features illustrated](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated), section 9. The expected/proposed syntax:

```
int.TryParse("5", out int x); // this declares (and assigns) a new variable x
```

*Edit:* This `out` variable syntax was eventually included in C# 7.0 (Visual Studio 2017); you can also use `out var x`.

---

Addition: People come up with fun extension methods. I tried to make a generic one:

```
public delegate bool TryParser<TResult>(string s, out TResult result);

public static class FunExtensions
{
  public static T TryParse<T>(this string str, TryParser<T> tryParser)
  {
    T outResult;
    tryParser(str, out outResult);
    return outResult;
  }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
  var x = "5".TryParse<int>(int.TryParse);
  var y = "01/01".TryParse<DateTime>(DateTime.TryParse);
  var z = "bad".TryParse<decimal>(decimal.TryParse);
```

and so on. I was hoping the compiler would infer `T` from usage, so that one could say simply:

```
  var x = "5".TryParse(int.TryParse);  // won't compile
```

but it appears you have to explicitly specify the type argument to the method.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you could create an extension:

```
public static int TryParse(this string input, int defaultValue = default(int))
{ 
    int intOutParameter;
    bool parsable = int.TryParse(input, out intOutParameter);
    if (parsable)
        return intOutParameter;
    else
        return defaultValue;
}
```

Then you don't even need an `out`-parameter:

```
int parsed = "5".TryParse(0);
```

Comment: But what if I want to make that more generic? I mean `Guid.TryParse` and `TimeSpan.TryParse` etc. I tried a generic extension in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP request:

```
private static bool IsIntValid(string str)
{
  int i = 0;
  return int.TryParse(str, out i);
}
```

Granted not the most cleverest approach however, the simplest I guess :) Can wrap this in an extension method also perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a temporary storage for all methods.

```
public static class Tmp<T>
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static T Value;
}
```

```
int x = int.TryParse("5", out Tmp<int>.Value) ? Tmp<int>.Value : 0;
```

Comment: very interesting, but is this efficient?

Comment: I don't see why this should be inefficient. No objects are created, only a generic type is built once it is used.